# Saving pictures to Camera roll with iOS charts

Tags: ios, swift, charts, ios-charts

I tried to save a graph, which I created with the iOS Charts api, to the camera roll. There exists only the following function:

```
private func saveButton() {
    barChartView.save(to: STRING, format: ChartViewBase.ImageFormat, compressionQuality: Double)
}
```

Which value should I enter for "to"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this

```
let a = barChartView.save(to: "\(AppDelegate.getAppDelegate().getDocDir())/chart.png", format: BarLineChartViewBase.ImageFormat.png, compressionQuality: 1.0)
```

The value which you can enter for "to" is the path where the chart will be saved.

In the previous version existed 2 methods

```
barChartView.saveToCameraRoll()
barChartView.saveToPath(path: String, format: ChartViewBase.ImageFormat, compressionQuality: Double)
```

Now just exist

```
barChartView.save(to: STRING, format: ChartViewBase.ImageFormat, compressionQuality: Double)
```

I don't know what is the path to the camera roll, but maybe just change the path 
and could work

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. In the meantime, I found another solution.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the same function which is use by Charts.

```
     let image = chartView.getChartImage(transparent: false)
     UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image!, nil, nil, nil)
```

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I found another solution:

```
public func saveGraph() {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
    view.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image!, nil, nil, nil)
}
```

This code is implemented into a ViewController which is called by from a PageViewController

Answer (score 2):

The answers above are all correct, however please make sure that when you do run code that saves to your camera roll, such as:

```
    let graphImage = myGraph.getChartImage(transparent: false)
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(graphImage!, nil, nil, nil)
```

That you have added the requirements of **NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription**("Privacy - Photo Library Additions Usage Description", this is now **required since iOS 11**) and the **NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription**(“Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description”) with the string text that you would like to display to the user (to explain why you need to save to the camera roll).

These requirements should be added to your **Info.plist** file, in your Xcode project.

Otherwise your app will crash when you run any code that saves an item to your camera roll.

I have attached a screenshot to show how this should look:

[image: Info.plist Photo Library Usage Description and Photo Library Additions Usage Description]

You can find more information about the Info.plist requirements [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html).